# Modelsim: Force string

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

My VHDL-testbench loads a text file. I want to be able to set the filename from the outside. As I'm using ModelSim (Altera starter edition) to simulate my design, it should be possible to set the string containing the filename over a force command or similar.

How can I "force" a VHDL-string to a certain value? What is the correct syntax?

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    use std.textio.all;
    use work.txt_util.all;

entity dpu_tb is
end dpu_tb;

architecture Behavioral of dpu_tb is
    signal clk: std_logic;
    signal simulation_finished: std_logic;
    signal simulation_input_file: string(1 to 100); --<-- Set value during simulation
    signal rst: std_logic;

    signal sample: std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
    signal valid: std_logic;

begin
    ....
```

What I tried and did not work (and different combinations):

```
force -deposit simulation_input_file "/tmp/test"
```

Or is there an different approach to choose the file?

Comment: As an alternative to "force", why not make it a generic?

Comment: How can I influence the generic from the outside of the simulator? (no change in VHDL file)

Comment: It'll be a command line option to vsim (if you're using modelsim). There ought to be a GUI "simulation option" for the purpose too, check the documentation if you're interested.

Comment: Vsim command use -g<genericname>=<value>

Comment: If the generic is an unconstrained string, you don't need to worry about the length either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the command reference manual by going to 'Help > Documentation - PDF Bookcase', you can find the complete syntax for this command.

It would be helpful if you included the error message and/or problem you saw, as opposed to simply "it didn't work", but in your case, it looks like you have have forgotten to include the full path to the signal you are driving. `simulation_input_file` should be `/dpu_tb/simulation_input_file`. In addition, to force a string, your force value must be the same length as the target string. If this is not convenient, you can make use of the TCL `format` command, for example:

`force /dpu_tb/simulation_input_file [format "%-100s" /tmp/test]`

You can look up the `format` command in the online TCL documentation to understand how this works.

Comment: "your force value must be the same length as the target string"

This was the problem. Thank you